# remove whole line from file with 2 column from a text file with 1 column in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

E.G

**File A**

abc 123

def 456

ghi 789

**File B**

def

**Resultfile**

abc 123

ghi 789

I tried it with sed, grep but it just won't work. I just stated learning linux and coudn't find anything similiar.

Thank you

//*-----------

grep -wvf  worked but now i see that i have a problem with sting where a "#" is in front. those will be removed too. By modifying to grep -w**x**vf, the command won't work at all. Do i need another command other than grep?

Comment: `grep -wvf fileB fileA` use `man grep`

Comment: That worked thanks. Another question: how is it with stings with a # infront? E.G abs 123 and #abc 123 and i want to remove only the line where  "#abc" is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}(!($1 in a)){print}' fileb filea
```

{a[$0];next}- this block executes until FNR==NR(which means for all lines of fileb). "next" ensures that no code gets executed after this block.

At the end of fileb line you have a associative array with key as lines in filb and value as null.

Then processing of lines in filea starts.

{print} will be executed for all lines in filea but on condition (!($1 in a))
which means print the lines in filea only if first field of filea is existing as a key in associative array a

Comment: This is a code-only answer, please expand it to help other users learn, not just dump code on them.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not able to reply to Ur comment I am posting here , in order to delete the line that begins with "#" try

sed '/^#/d' filea fileb